# Selenium java to find the right element

Tags: selenium

I want to find the the element for the Edit:

my java code is not working.

```
String xpathLocater = "//a[contains(text(),'onEditFilter('modifier')')]";
return driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpathLocater));
```

This is the source code for the element.

```
<tr class="listeven">
<td>
<a onclick="return onEditFilter('modifier');" href="#">Edit</a>
</td>

</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like

```
String xpathLocater = "//a[contains(@onclick,\"onEditFilter('modifier')\")]"
```